# Filter Linux kernel messages from console with syslog-ng

Tags: linux, kernel-messages

I'm working on a network management script with Dialog and I would like to suppress kernel messages from `ifconfig` and `brctl` so that they don't scroll the terminal and break the pretty Dialog screen.

I can redirect the easy things to `/dev/null` but I can't keep the info level kmsg stuff from printing to the console. The platform is headless and using syslog-ng to report to a remote server and I really don't need anything going to the console. Any solutions?

Trying to block messages like:

```
device eth0 left promiscuous mode
br0: port 1(eth0) entering disabled state
```

Comment: Have you considered changing permissions on /proc/kmsg?

Comment: The permissions are read-only for root user only (400) normally, and changing them to 000 doesn't solve the problem.